# Use transaction in sequelize Bulk create with include associations

Tags: sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

i am using sequelize into Nestjs, i am trying to insert a new contact in my contact table, i want to send a list of contacts into a bulkcreate function like this:

```
await this.contactModel.bulkCreate(contactosList,transactionHost, {
        include: [
          {
            model: Correo,
            as: 'correo',
          },
          {
            model: Telefono,
            as: 'telefono'
          }
        ]
      })
```

But i want this to be a transaction, at the top of my service im starting a Managed  sequelize transaction, if i passed the transaction into the second property in my function it says that is just expecting 2 arguments and received 3.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation `bulkCreate` doesn't support `include` option and supports `transaction` option.
So if you want to create contacts along with associated models then you need to create them in `for` loop like this:

```js
for (const contact of contactosList) {
  const newContact = await this.contactModel.create(contact, {
        include: [
          {
            model: Correo,
            as: 'correo',
          },
          {
            model: Telefono,
            as: 'telefono'
          }
        ],
        transaction // this option should be indicated right next to `include` option
      })
}
```